# How to Retain Content Control and Custom XML Schema from Docx to Google doc?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, google-docs, word-addins

As we have our own Microsoft word add-ins that built up on Microsoft platform. Now we want to support Microsoft documents(.docx) on Google doc platform. We are seeing few challenges on google doc when we are opening document(.docx) format.

1. We are not able to retain custom xml in google doc, when we are doing any modification in google doc.
2. We are not able to keep word content control in google doc. We can't see those content control in google doc.

In Addition to this, Once we have modified document in google doc, we are seeing google's own schema in custom xml. as in attached screen shot.

Microsoft Word Custom Schema :
[image]

Google Document Custom Schema:
[image]

Do we have any workaround to retain custom xml or content control in google doc platform? do we have any migration utility which could be retain all schema as it in google doc platform?

Comment: It's not a realistic scenario to constantly convert the format of your documents. If you use OneDrive and online MS apps instead of Google, all your problems go away, as the native format remains the same.

Comment: Thanks John for your comment. This is requirement for user who are using google docs. Regarding online MS word-addin with one drive will have separate requirement and it seems to be supported content control and custom xml in online word-addins.